# RavenDB Serialization of NameValueCollection

Tags: ravendb

We are trying to implement a custom logger for Elmah to log errors in a RavenDB database in an MVC5 application.

The Logging works perfectly but when we try to read the logs we get an exception for all properties of the Error Class that are of type NameValueCollection with the following error :

Cannot populate list type System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection. Path 'Error.ServerVariables'.

If we look at the json properties in the Ravendb document we can see that they have been stored as Arrays which is causing the problem. Is there any way to fix this.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JsonConverter to serialize/desieralize this propertly

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do we do this? Sorry but we are new to this and any help or a link would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If we put this code: TheDocumentStore.Conventions.CustomizeJsonSerializer = serializer => serializer.ObjectCreationHandling = (Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.ObjectCreationHandling)ObjectCreationHandling.Replace; it works - but does this affect any of our other documents ?